# How to suppress Ligatures in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, ligatures

I am using the Accanthis font in XeLaTex and it has unfortunate ligatures, especially abbreviations containing AE are converted to Æ.

I have controlled this by editing the accanthis.sty file to change \defaultfontfeatures to

```
 \defaultfontfeatures{
 Ligatures = NoRequired,...
```

instead of TeX, but this seems like a terrible solution.

How should I change a template to do the same thing?
At the moment, it contains

```
\usepackage{accanthis}
```

Is there a way of overriding the sty commands in the .tex file and not editing the .sty file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `accanthis` package, with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX does nothing more than loading the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{AccanthisADFStdNo3}[
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  %Scale=1,
  Ligatures={TeX,NoRequired},
]


\begin{document}

AE ae fi fl -- --- ``''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Your answer works in LaTeX. Unfortunately, the document starts life as an RMarkdown file and it gives "! Undefined control sequence.l.26 \setmainfont                 {AccanthisADFStdNo3}[". It nonetheless produces a .tex file that generates the document correctly. How frustrating! Looks like a question for the RMarkdown forum.

Comment: @user1683586 I guess you need to teach the conversion to do `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: Spot on @egreg! I uninstalled and reinstalled the fontspec package and now it works all the way through. I am a bit surprised that it ever worked in the first place. Many thanks.